# Error when inflating CardView

Tags: java, android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-support-library, android-cardview

I am using a RecyclerView to hold a list of CardViews. On my device running Lollipop 5.0.2, the app runs fine and the list displays the data correctly. however, on other pre-lollipop devices such as one running 4.4.2, I get the following error:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.CardView
```

I've searched up answers on StackOverflow, and most of them say that the problem is with my dependencies, but my build.gradle has all the latest dependencies that I need.

```
dependencies {
 compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
 compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.3'
 compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.3'
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
}
```

And this is the XML layout that is being referenced to in the LogCat:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="@drawable/ripple_background"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    card_view:cardElevation="2dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
    android:id="@+id/news_item_layout"
    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="1dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    ....
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

And here is the full LogCat report:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
        at com.macronews.macro.adapter.TopicsCursorAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(TopicsCursorAdapter.java:85)
        at com.macronews.macro.adapter.TopicsCursorAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(TopicsCursorAdapter.java:41)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:4121)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:3431)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:3340)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LayoutState.next(LayoutState.java:83)
        at android.support.v7.widget.StaggeredGridLayoutManager.fill(StaggeredGridLayoutManager.java:1337)
        at android.support.v7.widget.StaggeredGridLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(StaggeredGridLayoutManager.java:584)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:1988)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:2237)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4364)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4364)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4364)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4364)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:948)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4364)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4364)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1649)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1507)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1420)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4364)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4364)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1649)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1507)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1420)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4364)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4364)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1868)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1689)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4214)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
        at java.lang.
```

**EDIT**
The ripple background drawable is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ripple
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:color="@color/accent_color"/>
```

Comment: can you show the code of @drawable/ripple_background ? on pre-lollipop devices you cannot use the xml only supported on 5+...

Comment: Make sure you are importing the correct classes in your java file. (Ie. the support library ones)

Comment: yeah, I have throughout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the official notes of [appcompat v21](http://android-developers.blogspot.be/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html)

> Why are there no ripples on pre-Lollipop? A lot of what allows RippleDrawable to run smoothly is Android 5.0’s new RenderThread. To optimize for performance on previous versions of Android, we've left RippleDrawable out for now.

When trying to use ripple-drawables, you get errors on pre-lollipop (that's why it says line 2, it's the xml drawable). Use a different folder (drawable-v21) for ripples and use selectors in your normal drawables if you want a difference for different states.

Official support is not coming soon, I believe, because lollipop has a dedicated render-thread that no other version has.

Comment: Thanks, I got rid of the ripple background and it now works :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try removing following from cardview and check

```
card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    card_view:cardElevation="2dp"
  card_view:cardCornerRadius="1dp"
```